# Read Excel file in java with grouped rows and generate WBS code

Tags: java, excel, java-8, apache-poi

i am trying to read excel file into java code

file as grouped rows with indentation i am trying to generate work break structure for nested groupped row for eg 1.1.1

i have used apache POi 3.7

this is the code

```
public class ExcelReaderforHierarchy {
    
     public static boolean importExcel() throws Exception {
         boolean ret= false;
            try {
                String a_fileName = "E:\\groupedRow.xls";
                FileInputStream w_In = new FileInputStream(a_fileName);
                // Load the workbook
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(w_In);

                // Get the first sheet in the workbook
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                generateWBSCodes(sheet);

                ret = true;

                // Close the workbook and file input stream
              //  workbook.close();
              //  file.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
      private static void generateWBSCodes(Sheet sheet) {
            int currentLevel = 0;
            int groupIndex = 1;

            // Iterate over the rows in the sheet
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                // Check if the row is grouped
                if (isGroupedRow(row)) {
                    currentLevel++;
                    groupIndex = 1;
                }

                // Generate and print the WBS code
                String wbsCode = generateWBSCode(currentLevel, groupIndex);
                System.out.println("Row: " + row.getRowNum() + ", WBS Code: " + wbsCode);

                // Increment group index for the next row
                groupIndex++;
            }
        }

        private static boolean isGroupedRow(Row row) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
            try {
                 System.out.println("cellval -" + cell.getStringCellValue());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           
          
                HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (HSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle();
                if (cellStyle != null) {
                    short indentLevel = cellStyle.getIndention();
                    System.out.println("indentLevel -" + cellStyle.getIndention()); // THIS always returns 0
                    return indentLevel > 0;
                }
          
            return false;
        }

        private static String generateWBSCode(int level, int index) {
            StringBuilder wbsCodeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    wbsCodeBuilder.append(".");
                }
                wbsCodeBuilder.append(index);
            }
            return wbsCodeBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
```

problem is `cellStyle.getIndention();` always returns 0

hence i am not able todetect if it is a grouped row or not

also i am not getting any error...

[image: excel image]

Comment: [Apache POI 3.7 was released in 2010](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.7) - what happens if you try with a version released this decade?

Answer (score 1):

Using a more current version of Apache POI than the decade old version 3.7 would be a good idea.

But the reason for your problem I think will be the different ways to indent a cell value.

The following shows two possibilities:

First variant:

[image]

`A3`, `A4` and `A5` are indented using the cell style **Format Cells - Alignment - Horizontal:** Left (Indent) **- Indent:** 1, 2 and 3.

There 1 means 3 spaces. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.alignment?view=openxml-2.8.1.

> indent (Indent)   An integer value, where an increment of 1 represents 3
> spaces. Indicates the number of spaces (of the normal style font) of
> indentation for text in a cell.

Also possible using button **Increase indentation** [image] in Start ribbon bar.

Second variant:

[image]

`A10`, `A11` and `A12` are indented using preceding spaces. Thus cell values in `A9:A12` are:

```
User Project
   Home
      Project Profile
         Edit Project Status
```

Of course `short indentLevel = cellStyle.getIndention();` can only work for variant 1 used in `A3`, `A4` and `A5`. To support second variant, one needs to get the count of preceding spaces before the cell values.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcelCelllIndent {
    
 static short getIndention(Cell cell) {
  CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
  short indentLevel = cellStyle.getIndention();
  if (indentLevel == 0) {
   if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
    String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
    String lTrimCellValue = cellValue.replaceAll("^\\s*", "");  
    int precedingSpaces = cellValue.length() - lTrimCellValue.length(); 
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.alignment?view=openxml-2.8.1
    // indent (Indent)  An integer value, where an increment of 1 represents 3 spaces. 
    indentLevel = (short)(precedingSpaces / 3);
   }   
  }
  return indentLevel;  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xls"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    System.out.print(cell.getAddress() + ":");    
    System.out.print(cell);    
    CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
    short indentLevel = cellStyle.getIndention();
    System.out.print("; indention from CellStyle :" + indentLevel);    
    indentLevel = getIndention(cell) ;
    System.out.println("; indention from method :" + indentLevel);        
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Code uses current Apache POI 5.2.3.

---

On the other hand your screenshot shows grouped rows which also could be used to determine the numbering level. That is called the outline level of the row and has nothing to do with indentation. Using current Apache POI version, the outline level of a row can be get via [Row.getOutlineLevel](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getOutlineLevel--)

Complete example again:

[image]

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcelRowOutlineLevel {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xls"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   int outlineLevel = row.getOutlineLevel();
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    System.out.print(cell.getAddress() + ":");    
    System.out.print(cell);
    System.out.println("; outline level: " + outlineLevel);
   }
  }
 }
}
```